# Extract indices of sets of values greater than zero in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, find

I have an array of length `n`. The array has braking energy values, and the index number represents time in seconds.

The structure of array is as follows:

- `Index 1 to 140, array has zero values.` (Vehicle not braking)
- `Index 141 to 200, array has random energy values.` (Vehicle was braking and regenerating energy)
- `Index 201 to 325, array has zero values.` (Vehicle not braking)
- `Index 326 to 405, array has random energy values.` (Vehicle was braking and regenerating energy)

...and so on for an array of length `n`.

**What I want to do is to get starting and ending index number of each set of energy values.**

For example the above sequence gives this result:

```
141 - 200
326 - 405
...
```

Can someone please suggest what method or technique can I use to get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `diff` is a quick way to do this.

Here is a demo (see the comments for details):

```
% Junk data for demo. Indices shown above for reference
%    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
x = [0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 7, 9, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0];

% Logical converts all non-zero values to 1
% diff is x(2:end)-x(1:end-1), so picks up on changes to/from zeros
% Instead of 'logical', you could have a condition here, 
% e.g. bChange = diff( x > 0.5 );
bChange = diff( logical( x ) );

% bChange is one of the following for each consecutive pair:
%   1 for [0 1] pairs
%   0 for [0 0] or [1 1] pairs
%  -1 for [1 0] pairs
% We inflate startIdx by 1 to index the non-zero value
startIdx = find( bChange > 0 ) + 1; % Indices of [0 1] pairs
endIdx = find( bChange < 0 );   % Indices of [1 0] pairs
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to capture the edge cases where you add a start or end index if the array starts or ends with a non-zero value. Hint: you could handle each case separately or pad the initial `x` with additional end values.

Output of the above:

```
startIdx 
>> [4, 9]
endIdx
>> [6, 14]
```

So you can format this however you like to get the spans `4-6, 9-14`.

Comment: Thank you. I used your method and also manage to perform task by another method. Both are convenient. I will share both here.

Answer (score 0):

This task is performed by two methods Both works perfectly.

**Wolfie Method:**

```
bChange = diff( EnergyB > 0 );
startIdx = find( bChange > 0 ) + 1;  % Indices of [0 1] pairs
endIdx = find( bChange < 0 );        % Indices of [1 0] pairs
```

**Result:**

> startIdx =

```
     141
     370
     608
     843
```

> endIdx =

```
     212
     426
     642
     912
```

**Second Method:**

```
startends = find(diff([0; EnergyB > 0; 0]));
startends = reshape(startends, 2, [])';
startends(:, 2) = startends(:, 2) - 1
```

**Result:**

> startends =

```
     141         212
     370         426
     608         642
     843         912
```